# self.interfaceOrientation causing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to be called on iOS 4.x

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios4, autorotate

When I test my single view app under 4.x in the simulator or device, upon startup the main UIViewController's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method is called precisely 3046 times (on device) or 23777 times (on simulator) and then crashes.  ...updated...

UPDATE: Inside the method I have
`UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;`

This seems to be the culprit, it causes shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to be called again, therefore putting it into an infinite loop until it crashes.  Anyone know why?  It doesn't do this in iOS 5+

Answer (score 1):

if you need to do any processing on Orientation change event, use this method instead,

```
 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
    [self HandleOrientationChange:toInterfaceOrientation];
 }

 -(void) HandleOrientationChange:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation
  {}
```

Comment: Is it not advisable to put this type of code inside shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:?  Can you point me to documentation that says so?

Comment: Documentation just says: Do not attempt to get the value of the interfaceOrientation property. (and btw this method is depricated in ios 6.0)


http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I'll give that a try.